# Tomcat 8 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError unable to restart Tomcat

Tags: out-of-memory, tomcat8, restart

I'm unable to autorestart a Tomcat instance when an OOM occurs.
I tried several different versions of defining the XX:OnOutOfMemoryError value:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p;/application/tomcat/bin/start.sh'"
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p;./application/tomcat/bin/start.sh'"
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p;cd /application/tomcat8/bin/;./application/tomcat8/bin/start.sh"
```

But whatever I try, the start.sh script is never executed, the catalina.out reveals:

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p;/application/tomcat8/bin/start_commons.sh"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 28005"...
```

The Tomcat instance is succesfully killed but then nothing happens anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing really works is adding XX:OnOutOfMemoryError as follows:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' "
```

and having a separate script checking if the process is still running and if not restart the Tomcat instance.